# Merging lots of small portions of line to longer adjacent lines using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.5, dissolve

I have a hydrologic system split into 100 meter segments which is what I'm looking for, but I also have a lot of very small segments all over my system.

Is it possible to dissolve/merge those small segments automatically within the closest 100m segment next to it for segments smaller than 10m ?